# TradingView I am unable to resolve this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

`    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

```
const TradingViewScreener = () => {
useEffect(() => {
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.type = 'text/javascript'
script.src =
  'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-screener.js'
script.async = true
script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
  width: '1100',
  height: '523',
  defaultColumn: 'overview',
  defaultScreen: 'most_capitalized',
  showToolbar: true,
  locale: 'en',
  market: 'us',
  colorTheme: 'light',
})

const container = document.querySelector(
  '.tradingview-widget-container__widget',
)
container.appendChild(script)

return () => {
  container.removeChild(script)
}
```

}, [])

```
return (
<div className="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div className="tradingview-widget-copyright">
    <a
      href="https://www.tradingview.com/"
      rel="noopener nofollow"
      target="_blank"
    >
      <span className="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

)
}

export default TradingViewScreener

errori i am facing
VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading                                      'querySelector')
at widgetId._replaceScript (VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:3:2022)
at new widgetId (VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:3:705)
at new  (VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:3:592)
at VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:3:588
at VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:5:3051
at VM164 embed-widget-screener.js:5:3055`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.